# Named_struct inside array function is not working in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to spark sql. I am looking for the array(Named_struct()). however, when i'm converting the **spark SQL** query data to **JSON** it is displaying as below

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"abc",
   "Product":[
      [
         2512,
         "sdsf"
      ]
   ]
}
```

I'm using the below query as inner query. so , I don't want to use collect_list.
here is the query

```
    select
      id,
      name,   
      array(Named_struct('code', Code, 'description', Description)) AS Product 
    from
      data
```

Code to excute my query

```
    from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
sc_sql = SQLContext(sc)

#ExtractConfig
data = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load("D:/data.csv")
#RawPath

data.createOrReplaceTempView("data")

dataDetails = sc_sql.sql("select id, name, array(Named_struct('code', Code, 'description', Description)) AS Product from data").coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("json").save("D:/fileop6.json")

pandasDF = dataDetails.toPandas()

fileop = pandasDF.to_dict(orient ='records')
w = 'fileop5.json'
with open(w, "w") as outfile:
 json.dump(fileop, outfile)
```

data.csv contains as below

[image]

expected output:

```
{
       "id":1,
       "name":"abc",
       "Product":[
          {
             "Code":2512,
             "Description":"sdsf"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Thanks everyone in Advance!

Comment: is it not working ? what error you are getting ?

Comment: @Srinivas, It is not showing error .Final JSON is not as expected.

Comment: @mck, I have checked twice. the final json is not as expected. i'm running above code in **spyder application**

Answer (score 0):

Check below code. It is giving expected output.

```
spark.sql("select id, name, array(Named_struct('code', Code, 'description', Description)) AS Product from data").coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("json").save("/tmp/data/")
```

```
cd /tmp/data
cat part-00000-c34988c2-4ec6-4540-82dd-ff424983897d-c000.json

{"id":"1","name":"abc","Product":[{"code":"2512","description":"sdsf"}]}
{"id":"1","name":"asds","Product":[{"code":"2313","description":"3434"}]}
```

Comment: The above code is getting error as ** AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'show'**. Could please help me out.

Comment: Updated code, try to write dataframe data into file & check.

Comment: getting error  as **
An error occurred while calling o175.save.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems **

Comment: can you post your code in above question ?

Comment: updated the code in the question. please have look.